# Perimeter of a triangle with an angle of $120^\circ$ and sides in arithmetic progression

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> I need to find the perimeter of the following triangle in terms of $\ell$. 
>   The only extra info I have is the three sides form an arithmetic sequence.

[image]

I've been tutoring maths on these topics for a couple years now and I am still struggling with this problem. I'm sure there's something rather simple I can't see. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am pretty sure that there are not sufficient amount of information. We can also let the angle 120 to be a variable point, so I suppose the total perimeter wont be fixed.

Comment: It seems to me that this triangle is similar to triangle with sides 3, 5, 7.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

It is reasonable to assume that the sides of the triangle, have a form $a=3l-2d$, $b=3l-d$ and $c=3l$ for some $d>0$. You can use the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) as $$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos {2\pi\over 3}=a^2+b^2+ab$$and by substitution, first find $d$ then $a+b+c$.

Comment: why is it reasonable to assume sides of the triangle have that form at all?

Comment: Because this can be the only case that the sides form an arithmetic sequence alongside the side $3l$ being the largest side of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$, $b$ and $3l$ be sides-lengths of the triangle.

Thus, $2b=a+3l,$ or $a=2b-3l$ and
$$(2b-3l)^2+b^2+b(2b-3l)=(3l)^2$$ or
$$7b^2-15bl=0,$$ which gives
$$(a,b)=\left(\frac{9l}{7},\frac{15l}{7}\right)$$ and
$$a+b+c=\frac{45}{7}l.$$